# Is there a way to detect and if a button on a web page is not clicking using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to extract tables from a webpage,but apparently its a paginated website so below the python code i use

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import requests
import pandas as pd


# Set up the web driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('website_url')


tables =[]

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'tablepress tablepress-id-2 dataTable no-footer'})
tables.append(table)

# Click the next button and extract the second table
next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Next')))
next_button.click()
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'tablepress tablepress-id-2 dataTable no-footer'})
tables.append(table)

# Click the next button and extract the second table
next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Next')))
next_button.click()
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'tablepress tablepress-id-2 dataTable no-footer'})
tables.append(table)


driver.quit()


# Convert each table to a DataFrame and concatenate them into a single DataFrame
dfs = []
for table in tables:
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
    dfs.append(df)
df = pd.concat(dfs)
# Save the DataFrame as an Excel file
df.to_excel('tables.xlsx', index=False)
```

but i want to use a loop so as to loop through and check if the next button is clickable to keep scraping the data, the iteration never stops and i dont know what is wrong. Below is the updated code

```
while True:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'tablepress tablepress-id-2 dataTable no-footer'})
    tables.append(table)

    # Check if the "Next" button is clickable
    
    next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Next')))
    if not next_button.is_enabled():
        break

    # Click the "Next" button to go to the next page
    next_button.click()

# Close the web driver
driver.quit()

# Convert each table to a DataFrame and concatenate them into a single DataFrame
dfs = []
for table in tables:
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
    dfs.append(df)
df = pd.concat(dfs)

# Save the DataFrame as an Excel file
df.to_excel('tables.xlsx', index=False)
```

I have also updated the code using try/catch but its still iterating and never stops.

```
while True:
    # Extract the table
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'tablepress tablepress-id-2 dataTable no-footer'})
    tables.append(table)

    # Check if there is a next button
    try:
        next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Next')))
    except TimeoutException:
        break

    # Click the next button
    next_button.click()

driver.quit()



# Convert each table to a DataFrame and concatenate them into a single DataFrame
dfs = []
for table in tables:
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
    dfs.append(df)
df = pd.concat(dfs)
# Save the DataFrame as an Excel file
df.to_excel('tables.xlsx', index=False)
```

Below is the HTML of the Next button when it is clickable AND not clickable respectively

```
<a class="paginate_button next" aria-controls="tablepress-3" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0" id="tablepress-3_next">Next</a>
```

```
<a class="paginate_button next disabled" aria-controls="tablepress-3" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="-1" id="tablepress-3_next">Next</a>
```

Comment: Just try/catch the call... if you catch a timeout exception, you know it's not clickable.  (and the next_button will be null at that point...)

Comment: Please update your question with the HTML of the Next button when it is clickable AND not clickable. There will be some attribute differences between the two that we can create a locator for that you can then use to detect if it's clickable without resorting to `try-catch` exceptions.

Comment: @JeffC are you saying i just update my question with the HTML tag. Please can you elaborate more

Comment: @pcalkins i've also updated it with try/catch but its still the same

Comment: Yes, please edit your question and add the HTML I described in my previous comment.

Comment: @JeffC I have updated it as instructed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Next link is an A tag that has a 'disabled' class applied. When Selenium waits for clickable, it waits for visible and not disabled (attribute) but that generally only applies to INPUTs. So, Selenium thinks that the Next link is clickable (and it is) but it just does nothing if clicked because of the CSS applied. We can just change the locator to reflect the Next button in the correct state and it should work.

```
next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.next:not(.disabled)")))
```

The CSS selector `a.next:not(.disabled)` is looking for an A tag belonging to the class 'next' but not the class 'disabled'.